# Matlab, "tranpose(x)" not doing it right?

Tags: matlab

I just found this really weird thing in matlab,

when I do

```
  x = [1 2 3];

  tranpose(x)*x
```

I don't get $14$ as an output, but I get a 3 x 3 matrix

```
 1     2     3
 2     4     6
 3     6     9
```

Comment: You can use ' for transpose as in x'*x...

Comment: Beware! `'`  is **conjugate**-transpose. For transpose use `.'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `x*Transpose(x)` as x is an inverted vector.

`Transpose(x)` is a matrix with three rows and one collumn. `x`  is a matrix with one row and three collumns, thus 3by1 multiplied by 1by3 is according to the rules of matrix multiplication going to be a 3by3 matrix.

This is slightly unintuitive, but if you know matrix (and vector) multiplication, try to multiply these on your own:

$$
\left(\begin{array}  \text{1} \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array} \ 1 \ 2 \ 3\end{array}\right)
$$

Comment: Oh my goodness, I am an idiot.

Comment: Haha, I remember when (not so long ago) I first found out that vector*vector=matrix, I definitely took a bit of time (and thinking) to digest that.

Comment: No I didn't realize I defined x to be a row vector in matlab because I was lazy in making a column one.